# Regexp to match up to the last occurence of symbol

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out a PHP regexp.

Given multi-line string:

```
var Data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":1}}]}'
}

var Data = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":2}}]}'
};

// Some other text here that may have }; or }. Blahblah blah.
// };
// }
```

I need the following two matches from the string above:

```
Data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":1}}]}'
}

Data = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":2}}]}'
}
```

I've tried **`Data\s?=\s?{[^}]+};?`** but it matches:

```
Data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":1}

Data = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': '{"a":[{"b":{"id":2}
```

Question: **How do I change my regexp to achieve my goal?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if you are not sure about opening and closing braces if they occur in a an equal number, a general solution would be:

```
Data\s*=\s{(?:[^:}]*:.*\R+)+}
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vpiwi8/1)

Breakdown:

- `Data\s*=\s{` Match `Data={` with optional spaces between
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `[^:}]*:.*\R+` Match a line with following newline character
- `)+` Repeat as many as possible
- `}` Match ending brace

PHP code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HdiRE)):

```
preg_match_all('~Data\s*=\s{(?:[^:}]*:.*\R+)+}~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

But otherwise, to only refer to my comment, you are in need of subroutine calls and recursions that both PCRE have a support for:

```
Data\s*=\s*({(?:[^{}]*|(?1))*})
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/erMpZy/1)

Comment: Thanks! How do I tweak "Data\s*=\s*({(?:[^{}]*|(?1))*})" to additionally match "var " that optionally precedes "Data"? "(var\s+)?Data\s*=\s*({(?:[^{}]*|(?1))*})" does not seem to do anything

Comment: `(?1)` in second regex invokes first capturing group. When you add a capturing group at beginning you change this number. Either use a non-capturing group `(?:var\s+)?Data\s*=\s*({(?:[^{}]*|(?1))*})` or change `(?1)` to `(?2)`: `(var\s+)?Data\s*=\s*({(?:[^{}]*|(?2))*})`